# AdMob: advertising states receiving

Tags: admob

Is there any helper functions for AdMob to check out:

1. advertising displayed
2. advertising was clicked
3. advertising request successful, but no advertising returned due to lack of ad inventory

Answer (score 0):

On Android ?

Your Activity can implement AdListener in order to receive appropriate callbacks.

Callbacks are: onReceiveAd, onFailedToReceiveAd, onPresentScreen, onDismissScreen and onLeaveApplication.

See: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/mediation/

Answer (score 0):

When you have implemented the AdListener, in your callbacks you can insert some google analytics personal event to have a statistic.

Comment: Could you add some examples?